# MVC3 Multi-Part Form Posting Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm working on the following form

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("BusinessMedia", "SmallBusiness", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })){
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Business.BusinessID)
        <div style="padding-right:850px">
            @Html.Label(" ", "First Picture:")
            <input type="file" name="BusinessPictures" id="FirstPicture" />
            @Html.Label(" ", "Second Picture:")
            <input type="file" name="BusinessPictures" id="SecondPicture" />
            @Html.Label(" ", "Third Picture:")
            <input type="file" name="BusinessPictures" id="ThirdPicture" />
            @Html.Label(" ", "Fourth Picture:")
            <input type="file" name="BusinessPictures" id="FourthPicture" />
            @Html.Label(" ", "Fifth Picture:")
            <input type="file" name="BusinessPictures" id="FifthPicture" />
            @Html.Label(" ", "Video:")
            <input type="file" name="BusinessVideo" id="Video" />
            <div style="padding-left:40%; padding-bottom:63px;">
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Upload Media" />
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

and I cannot seem to understand why the BusinessID that is hidden in the form does not come through to the model in the controller.  The files come through fine.  This is the controller action.

```
    [HttpPost]
public ActionResult BusinessMedia(BusinessModel model, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> BusinessPictures, HttpPostedFileBase BusinessVideo)
{
    string VideoServerPath = Server.MapPath("~/videos/");
    string ImageServerPath = Server.MapPath("~/images/");
    if (model.SaveBusinessMedia(model, BusinessPictures, BusinessVideo, VideoServerPath, ImageServerPath))
        return PartialView("PostRentalSuccess", model);
    return PartialView("PostNewRental");
}
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Business Model Added

```
 public class BusinessModel
{
    public List<Business> RequestedBusinesses;
    public BusinessHour RequestedBusinessHours;
    public User User;
    public RentalContext _rc;
    public Business Business;
    public List<String> PictureLinks;

    public BusinessModel()
    {
        RequestedBusinesses = new List<Business>();
        RequestedBusinessHours = new BusinessHour();
        User = new User();
        _rc = new RentalContext();
        Business = new Business();
        PictureLinks = new List<string>();

    }

    public void LoadUser(int UserID)
    {
        User = (User)_rc.Users.Find(UserID);
    }

    public void ReturnBusinesses(int ServiceTypeID)
    {
        var BusinessesRequested = from b in _rc.Businesses
                                  where b.ServiceTypeID == ServiceTypeID
                                  select b;

        RequestedBusinesses = new List<Business>();
        foreach (var item in BusinessesRequested)
        {
            RequestedBusinesses.Add(item);
        }
    }

    public static Image ResizeImage(Image image, Size size)
    {

        int newWidth = size.Width;
        int newHeight = size.Height; 
        Image newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
        using (Graphics graphicsHandle = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
        {
            graphicsHandle.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            graphicsHandle.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
        }
        return newImage;
    }

    public void PicturesForBusiness(int BusinessID)
    {
        var Pictures = from p in _rc.Pictures
                       where p.BusinessID.Value == BusinessID
                       select new { p.PictureLink };
        if (Pictures.Count() > 0)
            foreach (var item in Pictures)
                PictureLinks.Add(item.PictureLink);
    }

    public void LoadBusiness(int BusinessID)
    {
        Business = (Business)_rc.Businesses.Find(BusinessID);
        PicturesForBusiness(Business.BusinessID);
        ReturnBusinessHours(Business.BusinessID);
    }

    public void ReturnBusinessHours(int BusinessID)
    {
        var BusinessHoursRequested = from bh in _rc.BusinessHours
                                     where bh.BusinessID == BusinessID
                                     select bh;
        if (BusinessHoursRequested.Count() > 0)
            foreach (var item in BusinessHoursRequested)
                RequestedBusinessHours = item;
    }

    public bool SaveBusinessMedia(BusinessModel model, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> BusinessPictures, HttpPostedFileBase BusinessVideo, string VideoServerPath, string ImageServerPath)
    {
        int recordCount = 0;
        Image Resized;
        FileStream SmallPicture;
        model.LoadBusiness(model.Business.BusinessID);
        Business BusinessUser = (Business)from b in _rc.Businesses
                                          where b.BusinessID == model.Business.BusinessID
                                          select b;
        model.LoadUser(BusinessUser.UserID);
        int result = 0;
        try
        {
            if (BusinessPictures != null)
            {
                foreach (HttpPostedFileBase requestFile in BusinessPictures)
                {
                    if (requestFile.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(requestFile.FileName);
                        if (!Directory.Exists(ImageServerPath))
                        {
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(ImageServerPath);
                        }
                        string path = Path.Combine(ImageServerPath, fileName);
                        requestFile.SaveAs(path);
                        Picture Picture = new Picture();
                        Picture.BusinessID = model.Business.BusinessID;
                        Picture.Description = model.Business.Name;
                        Picture.PictureLink = "/images/" + fileName;
                        Picture.UploadedBy = model.User.UserID;
                        Picture.UploadedOn = DateTime.Now;
                        _rc.Pictures.Add(Picture);
                        recordCount++;
                        Resized = ResizeImage(Image.FromFile(path), new Size(75, 75));
                        string fileExt = fileName.Substring(fileName.IndexOf('.'), fileName.Count() - fileName.IndexOf('.'));
                        fileName.Remove(fileName.IndexOf('.'), fileName.Count() - fileName.IndexOf('.'));
                        path = Path.Combine(ImageServerPath, fileName + "_s" + fileExt);
                        Resized.Save(path, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                        Picture.PictureLink = "/images/" + fileName;
                        _rc.Pictures.Add(Picture);
                        recordCount++;                                             
                    }
                }
            }

            if (BusinessVideo.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(BusinessVideo.FileName);
                if (!Directory.Exists(VideoServerPath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(VideoServerPath);
                }
                string path = Path.Combine(VideoServerPath, fileName);
                BusinessVideo.SaveAs(path);
                Video Video = new Video();
                Video.BusinessID = model.Business.BusinessID;
                Video.Description = model.Business.Name;
                Video.VideoLink = "/videos/" + fileName;
                Video.UploadedBy = model.User.UserID;
                Video.UploadedOn = DateTime.Now;
                _rc.Videos.Add(Video);
                recordCount++;
            }
            result = _rc.SaveChanges();
            if (result == recordCount)
                return true;
            else
                return false;

        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
        {
            foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                    eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                        ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            throw;
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please post your `BusinessModel` class.

Comment: Have you setted the ID into Bussiness object? As I can see, you only instanciate the object, not setting the ID value.

Comment: The model is populated in the action that loads this form.  I've confirmed this.

Comment: Ok, but look at your model constructor. In the line where you instance Bussiness object, you just create a new instance. Try to add any value into the ID property and see the generated HTML after the page load. Tell us if the ID value is filled into the hidden field.

Comment: You sir win the prize.  Always something simple.  Thank you Kiwanax.